# Bluetooth Image Printing

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I m working on a Bluetooth Printing app.
I m using MOB-80 Thermal Printer configration is-`8dotsper/mm,203dpi` 
So to print a image we need to convert image in bmp formap(1 bit pixel or 1bpp)
We allready convert it but how we calculate byte of bmp image which i can send to printer
with

```
COMMAND: 0D 1D 76 30 00 XL XH YL YH DATA
```

when i calculate byte using code

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);

input.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);  //input is 1bpp bitmap image

byte[] data = buffer.array();
```

data size is not equal to image byte size which is shown in paint when we open it in paint.

i m so confused with this

But image is not printing..please suggest me.

Comment: I found the solution of image printing on bluetooth printer,,but image quality is only black and white..we can not identify the picture which is printed... the steps i followed is--
1. reduce image size according to printer configuration
2. convert it into 1bpp monocrome image 3. and send byte array to printer with above commend but the problem is that image is black and white(0/1 only).So i need to apply dithering on image..
there is a floyd dithering concept in image processing but i m fail to apply this.. plz help me...